# set a Powershell Data Entry to non Resizeable

Tags: powershell

I am programming Windows Powershell since 2 months and I haven't found anything about the resizeability of an input window. In Java there is something called 'setResizeable(true/false)' but I didn't find anything like that in the internet.

Thanks for your time and support :D

Comment: What kind of "input window"? A Form? A WPF window?

Comment: uhm yeah a form (sorry forgot to mention that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`FormBorderStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the form to [`Sizable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms > $null
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing > $null

$Form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 250,400
$Form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Sizable
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

[image: Sizable form]

Comment: **Thanks!** You helped me a lot!